# SmoothDensityHistogram with logarithmic density

Tags: visualization, histograms, scaling

Is there a simple way for making `SmoothDensityHistogram` plots have logarithmic scaling for the density? With `DensityHistogram` it's a simple matter of `{"Log","PDF"}` for the *hspec* argument, but `SmoothDensityHistogram` doesn't have a native option.

Comment: `ScalingFunctions -> "Log"`?

Comment: For some reason that doesn't work for me. Try: `data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 100000];` `DensityHistogram[data, Automatic, {"Log", "PDF"}]` versus `SmoothDensityHistogram[data, ScalingFunctions -> "Log"]`.

The second plot doesn't return anything resembling the first.

Comment: It's just choosing a weird plot range because the density is nearly 0 (so the log tends to $-\infty$) in most of the plot. With for example `PlotRange -> {-5, Automatic}` you get what you expect.

Comment: Yes I see. I suppose the real problem is not the lack of a `"Log"` option but the lack of a `"Count"` option. `DensityHistogram` allows for `"Count"` in hspec which plays nice with `"Log"`, but `"PDF"`, by definition, doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my comments as an answer:

Use `ScalingFunctions -> "Log"`. However, as the value of the log-PDF tends to $-\infty$ away from the data, you'll have to set the `PlotRange` manually to get a reasonable-looking plot.

```
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 1000];
SmoothDensityHistogram[data, ScalingFunctions -> "Log", PlotRange -> {-4, Automatic}]
```

[image]

For comparison:

```
DensityHistogram[data, Automatic, {"Log", "PDF"}]
```

[image]

It would be nice to have an automatic way to pick the lower bound, but that will depend on the number of data points and the spread of the data. Maybe if you can find out the bandwidth of the kernel function being used by `SmoothDensityHistogram` you can get the right value, but I don't know how to do that.